# huffman coding for a text file

Tags: ocaml, huffman-code

This is only part of my huffman tree generated using ocaml. The tree is represented as (char*int list) list:

```
[(' ', [0]); ('e', [1; 0]); ('t', [1; 1; 0]); ('a', [1; 1; 1; 0]);
 ('o', [1; 1; 1; 1; 0]); ('n', [1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0]).....].
```

The `(char*int list)` is the code and the corresponding encoded bitstream. I'm wondering if this is a correct tree or I understood something wrong. In this way, the longest encoded ASC II code will be 255 bits. The original file is `213.3k` and after encoding, it becomes `227k` while in the instructions, I was told it should generate a file around `119k`. I don't know where my problem is because I did everything following the instructions. Can someone tell me what is wrong in here?

My biggest problem is that: if I use huffman coding, only the 8 most frequent chars can save me space while the other 247 chars will cost extra space, is that true? If it isn't, why?

The codes I wrote was following the instructions in this link:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs3110/2012sp/hw/ps3/ps3.html

This is my code of encoding function:

```
type huffmantree = Node of huffmantree*(int*int)*huffmantree 
 | Leaf of char*int | Nil
type encoding = char * (int list)

let look_up (chr: char) (encl : encoding list) : int list =
  let rec look_up_rec encl = 
    match encl with
    | [] -> raise (Failure "Not found")
    | (ch,theL)::tl -> if ch = chr then theL
                       else look_up_rec tl
    in
    look_up_rec encl
;;

let get_codes (hm : huffmantree): encoding list = 
  let rec get_codes_rec aTree word=
  match aTree with
  | Nil -> []
  | Node (Leaf(lKey,lFreq),value,Nil) -> [(lKey,[0])]
  | Node (Leaf(lKey,lFreq),value,Leaf(rKey,rFreq)) ->  
    [(lKey,List.append word [0]);(rKey,List.append word [1])]
  | Node (Leaf(lKey,lFreq),value,rNode) -> 
    (lKey,List.append word [0])::(get_codes_rec rNode (List.append     word [1]))
  in
  get_codes_rec hm []
;;

let encode (text : char list) : huffmantree * int list = 
  let sortedT = List.fast_sort (fun ch1 ch2->   
    if (int_of_char ch1)>=(int_of_char) ch2 then 1 else -1) text
  in
  let rec cre_freq_list aList m = 
    match aList with
    | [] -> []
    | hd::[] -> [(hd,m+1)]
    | hd1::hd2::tl -> if hd1=hd2 then cre_freq_list (hd2::tl) (m+1)
                      else (hd1,(m+1))::(cre_freq_list  (hd2::tl) 0)
  in
  let sortedF = List.fast_sort (fun (ch1,fr1) (ch2,fr2) ->
    if fr1>=fr2 then 1 else -1) (cre_freq_list sortedT 0)
  in
  let rec createHuff sortedF= 
    match sortedF with
    | [] -> Nil
    | (ch,va)::[] -> Node (Leaf (ch,va),(256,va),Nil)
    | (ach,aval)::tl -> 
      let rec creH_rec the_tl sib n freq= 
        match the_tl with
        | (bch,bval)::[] -> Node(Leaf (bch,bval),(n,bval+freq),sib)
        | (bch,bval)::btl -> creH_rec btl 
          (Node (Leaf (bch,bval),(n,bval+freq),sib)) (n+1) 
          (freq+bval)
    in creH_rec tl (Leaf(ach,aval)) 256 aval
  in
  let huff = createHuff sortedF
  in
  let rec make_codes text = 
    match text with
    | [] -> []
    | hd::tl -> List.append (look_up hd (get_codes huff)) 
      (make_codes tl)
  in
  (huff,(make_codes text))
```

Comment: Give us your code so that we can help you.

Comment: ... and maybe the instructions as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the resulting tree, it appears that you don't implement the Huffman's algorithm. I doubt the 'e' is more frequent in your text than any other letter. Without your code I can only guess but maybe when merging the two lightest trees you inserted the resulting tree at the end  of the list of trees to merge instead of inserting it at the right place according to its weight.

In your code `createHuff` is declared recursive but there is no recursive call.
Your function `createHuff` never compares the values inside the `sortedF` list don't you think this is a problem? It means that `createHuff` will always yield the same tree (with different labels but with the same structure).

Comment: "after removing the rec keyword from createHuff function, it still gives me the same result." of course. The problem is that `createHuff` should be recursive (that's why you put a `rec` in the first place).

Comment: As I told you in the answer, your function `createHuff` doesn't care about the frequencies , so how can it put light subtrees at the bottom and heavy ones at the top?

Comment: your tree does not compile

Comment: but it looks like it has only one branch, which is obviously wrong

Comment: I figured what you mean and am working on the tree now. I really didn't understand structure of huffman tree yesterday and wrote a lot of stuff that didn't make any sense. So I deleted them. Thank you for your time.